# Colors in git-prompt.sh output

Tags: git, bash, prompt

I'm trying to modify git-prompt.sh to replace the */+ repo state indicators with more readable versions, such as "changes" / "staged files".

Just changing the text is easy enough, but I also want different colors for them. Simply pasting some color escape sequences such as `\[\e[33m\]` into the state description strings does not work; the escape sequences etc are just dumped into the output.

Is there some way I can have the colors understood by bash when output from the git-prompt.sh script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have to use the `tput` colors.

Example from https://gist.github.com/trey/2722934#gistcomment-1835441

```
YELLOW="\[$(tput setaf 3)\]"
RESET="\[$(tput sgr0)\]"

PS1="\h:\W \u\$(__git_ps1 \" ${YELLOW}(%s)${RESET} \")\$ "
```

See also https://raymii.org/s/snippets/Bash_Bits_Add_Color_Output_To_Your_Scripts.html and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/269077/tput-setaf-color-table-how-to-determine-color-codes for list of colors.

Comment: To clarify, these changes are not in .bashrc (it already worked there when setting PS1 and calling __git_ps1, but all of its output would get a single color), but rather in git-prompt.sh itself. However, using tput does work in there. The only thing is it would also output \[ \] in the result, so I removed those and got the result I wanted. Thanks!